# Accessing a child element in webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

HTML code:

```
<pre> 
<span class="cm-string">"userId"</span>
 ":" 
<span class="cm-string">"abc"</span>
 ","
 </pre>
<pre>
 <span class="cm-string">"password"</span>
 ":" 
<span class="cm-string">"xyz"</span> 
"," 
</pre>
```

I need to access xyz value from abc value. 
The value of xyz keeps changing on every login so I need an xpath from abc.
I tried the following code but it failed:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[. = '\"abc\"']/followingsibling::span[2]");
```

Comment: Is the value always in the second `<pre>`, second `<span>`? if so I would write a query that uses those positions to get the element.

Comment: Yes you are right, use second <pre>, second <span>... Access from  first <pre>,second <span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will work with Selenium, but following xpath

```
//span[. = '"userId"']/ancestor::pre/following-sibling::*/span[2]/text()
```

gets result

```
"xyz"
```

For getting the text with Selenium, the expression seems to be

```
driver.getText(By.xpath("//span[. = '"userId"']/ancestor::pre/following-sibling::*/span[2]");
```

as found on [http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29)
`getElement` needs a node instead of the text, `getText` should result in the text of the element.

Comment: ERROR:Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//span[. = '\"abc\"']/ancestor::pre/following-sibling::*/span[2]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: @user3174553 Do you expect to get the whole span or just the value?

Comment: just the value -"xyz"

Comment: @user3174553 Updated my answer, but it's a bit guessing as the xpath is correct, only a selenium issue now as getElement would only accept an element (the span), but not the text. "Guessing" as I don't know yet if "getText" works in combination with "By.xpath" or e.g. if you should first get the element and then get the text.